# Can't delete a file even though I'm on an administrator account, and I have full ownership of the file?

Tags: windows-10, permissions

Downloaded an installer. Ran it. Didnt like the program so I uninstalled it. However, the installer file is still on my desktop.

Windows 10 64 bit.

I'm on an administrator account.

I right clicked on the file and went to properties and then security and looked at the ownership. I have full control.

[image: Permissions]

Found a link on superuser and it said try doing takeown from the cmd. I tried that. All it said was access denied even though I ran cmd as an administrator.

Found another post on here that said run explorer as an administrator. Tried that. Still getting access denied.

I know if I reboot my PC I'll stop getting the message and I'll be able to delete the file. I just want to know why I need to restart my machine to unlock the file. There has to be a way to do it without restarting my pc or downloading an unlocking program.

Comment: You write "I know if I reboot my PC I'll stop getting the message and I'll be able to delete the file" <-- not always the case!   sometimes the only way is  booting off eg an OS on USB , linux being a good one.   You're right that you might not have to restart and you might not have to run an unlocker program.. Things is sometimes unlocker programs can't unlock or delete the file either!  also unlocker program is no hassle.  Sometimes if messing around in windows without restarting and without even an unlocker program,just to delete a file is too much hassle then trying other methods is easier

Comment: also there might be more than one form of access denied message, so you should quote the message exactly, even giving a screenshot of it too.

Comment: also in this case you've tried almost nothing to delete the file, which is strange since you seem quite committed to trying things without restarting. One thing you could use is process explorer which you'd see mentioned in any discussion about a file that won't delete.

Answer (score -1):

I'm running Windows 10.

Uninstall or delete files from the "This PC" folder.  You will be recognised as the administrator.

If you use the "OS (C:)" folder you will be denied access.

Comment: Cant try it right now. Are you sure? Do you have a reference?